# Tensorflow: How to subtract a mean image?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm looking for a code snippet on how to subtract a mean image from an input image. I have the image mean as a numpy array:

```
IMG_MEAN = np.array((104.00698793,116.66876762,122.67891434), dtype=np.float32)
```

I guess the subtraction part will be something like

```
img = tf.subtract(img, mean_img)
```

but how to create the `mean_image` with the same shape as img?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assume img is all one matrix, size is (100, 100, 3)
rgb mean is [1, 2, 3]

```
img = tf.ones([100, 100, 3], dtype=tf.float32) #(100, 100, 3)
mean = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32) # (3)
mean = tf.reshape(mean, [1, 1, 3])

img_m = img - mean

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = sess.run(img_m) # shape of a (100, 100, 3)
    # a[:,:,0] = 0
    # a[:,:,1] = -1
    # a[:,:,1] = -2
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use `tf.image.per_image_standardization` as in: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`img = tf.subtract(img, mean_img)` is correct as long as the last dimension of `img` (`tf.shape(img)[-1]`) is 3.

You can check [Broadcasting operation in tensorflow Glossary](https://www.tensorflow.org/resources/glossary) and [numpy Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for further information.

> how to create the mean_image with the same shape as img?

You can try:

```
tf.reshape(tf.tile(m, [tf.reduce_prod(tf.shape(img)[:-1])]),
           tf.shape(img)).eval()
```